# Is there a way to play a Java InputStream with video xhtml tags OR include an authorization header with video xhtml tags?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have been trying to integrate an API that serves images and videos with another project and am struggling with xhtml/primefaces playing videos. I should mention that we were previously serving videos from the local file system with a video tag and that I have successfully integrated the API with two other projects with no issues.

The moment I try to include video tags or p:media tags I can't get the video to play on this project. I should mention that I didn't give primefaces a fair chance because none of the video players were supported for the project because they are not pre-installed and we don't want it to be a hassle to play a simple video because it wasn't a hassle before. I don't want to use primefaces if it can be helped.

Anyway here is my code snippet for downloading the video. I have tried all ways that are commented out as well and none worked (and performance for Base64 videos was abysmal).

```
    @SneakyThrows
public InputStream downloadVideoFromBlob() {
    String authorizationHeader = "XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX";
    String videoUrl = getUrlVideo(); //returns an https url
    try {
        URL url = new URL (videoUrl);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream in = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
        return in;
        //return new DefaultStreamedContent(in, "video/mp4");
        //ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        //int n = 0;
        //while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
        //{
        //  out.write(buf, 0, n);
        //}
        //out.close();
        //in.close();
        //return out.toByteArray();
        //return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(out.toByteArray()));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and here is the video tag code:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls="controls"  autoplay="autoplay" oncontextmenu="javascript:return false;">
    <source src="#{bean.downloadVideoFromBlob()}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

EDIT:
TLDR:
I don't want to install a third party video player which makes prime faces less desirable than an xhtml video tag. I just want to add an auth header to a url for an xhtml video tag if possible.

Comment: I'm looking for video in specific and mentioned that p:media is the less preferred solution over xhtml's video tag.

Comment: I had not noticed your attempt to also return StreamedContent and retracted my close vote. Possibly a work around in analogy to this is helpful: [Get concrete URL of <p:graphicImage> returning StreamedContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216665/get-concrete-url-of-pgraphicimage-returning-streamedcontent/54997693#54997693)

Comment: Why does the normal video tag not work (assuming you use the same in the other apps)

Comment: All the above solutions wound up having a blank video. I'm not sure why it wasn't working.

Comment: I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent to be a duplicate. Please check

Comment: I'm not having any trouble displaying images. In fact the API I'm using services both images and videos but the videos I can't get to display whereas the images display just fine.